# How can I display a console for visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I’m using [Live HTML Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer), and I have things getting outputted via `console.log(‘something’)`. Is there any way I can see the log in visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

The extension page says "Note: Javascript is not supported in preview", so probably not.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any live previewer that does support `console.log`?